# setInputType for EditText without losing multiLine feature?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

For some reason using `setInputType` for `EditText` forces it into a single line. I need the EditText to accept **NumberSigned**.

I tried using `InputFilter` such that it returns "" if `source.charAt(i)` is not 0-9 or dot or + or -

But how to allow newline character? I need to be able to enter in multiple lines in the EditText.

I tried both in xml and code:

```
et = new EditText(this);

et.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.default_value));

et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);

et.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

linearLayout.addView(et);
```

the setText enters a string:

```
<string name="default_value">1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9</string>
```

which is shown as 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.

I tried using `setLines()` and `setMaxLines()` but no luck.
I think the reason it is forced into a single line is because newline character is not a part of InputType NumberSigned.

Comment: What is the `layout_height` attribute set to in the xml?

Comment: It is set to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Can you post the related xml code and java (if any)?

Comment: Yeah sure. I have created the EditBox in code. But I tried in xml too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want input as signed integer, then you can use

`...`

`android:digits="0123456789 \n"`

`...`

PS : Don't forget the SPACE between `9` and `\n`

Comment: There is no such funtion as setDigits() !!

Comment: Sorry for that, but its available with XML